How complete is the quantum tunneling theory of alpha decay and what are some alternatives?
In a lot of texts $\alpha$ decay is described through a relatively simple quantum tunneling model. An $\alpha$ particle within the attractive strong force potential has some probability of escaping through tunneling, and with this concept you can make interesting theoretical predictions like the Geiger-Nuttall law. But it seems that this model is certainly not a full explanation of the phenomenon. For example, a couple points that can be raised:

How are the alpha particles formed within the nucleus, and how does that alter the decay?

Why don't nuclei decay through other massive particles like a $^3$H nucleus or a $^6$Li nucleus? Why only $^4$He?


Are there more complete models that attempt to explain these kinds of questions and others?

For 2., consider the binding energy of αs.

But there are other configurations with similar $B$ or higher,correct?

Linked and also.

"Actually, as pointed out by JoeHobbit, the real mystery isn't why we don't emit larger clusters, it's why we don't emit lighter objects like protons or deuterons. A proton doesn't have to worry about preformation, and its tunneling probability would be much higher. "
Seems like there are still some questions regarding this problem.

...he then starts the discussion... I assume that is what you are trying to expand? Why not pursue that thread?
